# IIS 10 gives blank screen

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-10

I'm trying to launch my ASP.NET Core application.

I have installed IIS on a Windows Server, and installed the AspNetCore Module relevant, as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.1#install-the-net-core-hosting-bundle

How-ever, trying to access the website returns simply a white page, no exception or error pages. I have looked in event viewer as well, nothing.

If i take the source code, and in command prompt run `dotnet run` the application does work in the environment, but the output from `dotnet publish -o publish` does not work on IIS.

I'm at this point mostly looking at ways to get IIS to actually spit out some error codes. Too difficult to find the needle, when I dont even have the (hay)stack.

Edit:
I have tried to make a new "blank" application using the same configuration. This works fine, hence i now believe its my code that's to blame. Yet, it all works fine in visual studio. I really need it to spit out some debugging information, but I don't know how to make it do that.

Information from Fiddlr:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Kestrel
Date: Tue, 04 Dec 2018 15:13:22 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

Comment: Please ensure that you followed ALL of these steps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/

Comment: I have followed this guide to set up. Only difference is deployment process, where i upload the files via FTP after having used dotnet publish.

Comment: Tell specifically what do you mean by installed the AspNetCore Module relevant?

Comment: If you see the guide mentioned by Peter B, the section `Install the .NET Core Hosting Bundle`

Comment: Use a tool like Fiddler to check every bits of the blank response page (HTTP headers, status code, and so on), and that might give more hints on what's up.

Comment: I have added the response from fiddlr. Not really anything i find helpful, but thanks :D

Comment: I removed some error handling middleware, and now the server is actually returning a http 500 error, but no actual information, not even from local

Comment: Try to add `app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();` outside of `if (env.IsDevelopment())` to check excetpion. Try [stdoutLogEnabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/aspnet-core-module?view=aspnetcore-2.2#log-creation-and-redirection) to check whether there is any error.

Comment: Thank you @TaoZhou ofcause. Why had i not thought of that! Found the bugs! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the bugs.

It was a missing environment variable used in the application throwing an internal exception.

By recommendation of @Tao Zhou, to simply make sure to use the developer exception page, and then fix the bugs.

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was the fact that the app has a default app.UseHttpsRedirection() and there were no bindings for HTTPS so it was throwing an error about not knowing which port to use.